# Git pull does not work after upgrading macOS

Tags: git, macos

I use git in my macOS and after I upgrade macOS to latest version, I cannot use git pull successfully. This is error message I get:

```
Fatal: java.lang.Error encountered.  Details:
unexpected error
fatal: credential helper '!/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Ddebug=false -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true -jar /usr/local/Cellar/git-credential-manager/2.0.3/libexec/git-credential-manager-2.0.3.jar' told us to quit
```

I try to change jave10 to jave8, but the command still look for jave10. Does anyone know where can I config this?

Comment: Did you install that Java-based credentials helper? Does Java itself still work? Is that credential-helper still there? Does it produce any log files?

Comment: How can I knoe I install java-based credentials helper? Java itself can work

Comment: After I reinstall credentials helper it can work.